# nvgstcapture vs nvarguscamerasrc

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

I bought a CSI camera, IMX219, for my OpenCV project.

When I run the below command, there seems to be no delay at all in showing the frames in realtime.

`$ nvgstcapture-1.0 -m 2 --prev-res 4`

However, when I run my simple python code using the below pipleline, capturing is significantly slow,

```
pipeline = 'nvarguscamerasrc !  video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1920, height=1080, format=NV12, framerate=30/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

What should I do if I need 1920x1080, 30fps VideoCapture() in Opencv?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a similar question I asked on the NVIDIA devloper forums:https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/optimizing-opencv-gstreamer-with-mipi-and-usb-uvc-cameras/123665/27

Basically, the issue is that you lose a lot of the hardware acceleration in the gstreamer pipeline for OpenCV. `videoconvert` in particular is very slow in the pipeline. With the nature of my application, I used `nvvidconv` to convert from BGRx to I420. OpenCV can't handle BGRx, but it can do I420 which I convert to BGR for processing in later parts of my application. `appsink` is also slow on their devices and you don't have another option for the sink.

If you need constant real time frames, I would recommend using the [libargus API](https://docs.nvidia.com/jetson/l4t-multimedia/group__LibargusAPI.html) as that probably has the highest performance being provided by NVIDIA and optimized for their hardware.

Comment: libargus API sounds promising. I think that's exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you so much!